# Tiny Mce - iframe is not working it display directly url

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube, tinymce

In tiny mce if use iframe youtube video link. The video does not play instead of it displays like

Answer (score 1):

The problem is iframe tag stored in database like <iframe> instead of .

just replace the "&lt" to < and "&gt" to > then store the database like

Now the video is playing fine